# GAC locking problem when running deployment

Tags: deployment, dll, gac

We have a NANT script that uses msbuild to compile our visual studio solutions and deploys the .dlls into the GAC.

This works well on our integration/test servers as part of continuous integration, cruise control uses the NANT scripts and every time the dlls are put into the GAC without problem.

On our local development machines, where we use subversion/vs.net etc. for development, frequently certain dlls do not make it to the GAC when we run the build.

We think we have narrowed this down to visual studio and/or a plug in locking the GAC or the dlls for some reason. Strangely if we run the build a second time all the dlls make it to the GAC.

We have added various iisreset's to the NANT script in the hope of releasing the lock but to no avail.

Can anyone suggest a good approach to attack this problem?

All the best

Comment: This seems better suited for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

how are you putting objects into the GAC? does NANT have a feature for doing this?

In the past I have used gacutil.exe as part of a post build step (VS project) to achieve this on developer machines.